# Force lower case of URLs - Override previous rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have inherited a rather scary looking .htaccess file that is filled with previous rules.  What I am trying to do is simply make every single URL lowercase for SEO reasons.  Currently Google Webmasters is complaining about duplicate pages. eg: www.example.com/AbC1.php has the same content as www.example.com/abc1.php.  To solve this I placed the following lines into my vhosts.conf

```
#Make URL's lower case
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond \$1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /\${lowercase:\$1} [R=301,L]
```

But due to one of the many rules I have in my .htaccess file this rule isn't working.  Can I add that above rule and ensure that it overrides any other rules?

Comment: You're better of deploying canonical tag to each page and [you cannot use `RewriteMap` on `.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)

Comment: @Prix, that is actually a really easy and simple solution, especially seeing as I already have the canonical tag.  I'll just place a simple "strtolower". Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add it above any other rules in your htaccess file but the rewrite map definition must be in your vhost config, so in vhost:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
```

And in the very top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```

(note that you don't need to leading slash)

Comment: @JohnCrawford you have rules in any other htaccess file besides your document root? It'll need to be in all of them if you want it to affect your entire site

Comment: I tried this but still no luck.  Here are my files, but please note that they really need some TLC. http://pastebin.com/LvwE17a8 (root htaccess file) http://pastebin.com/XJnUitU1 (UK folder), http://pastebin.com/nssMwKH7 (vhost file)

Comment: @JohnCrawford Oh I see what the problem is, you've escaped the `$1` in the condition, that means you **literally** want to match against a `$1` instead of the request URI's pathinfo.

Comment: nice spotting.  I have no idea how that happened as I just copied n pasted that code.  Anyway that seems to have fixed the issue. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want this to apply to existing files and folder names, so I changed the .htaccess part of [Jon Lin's excellent solution to:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19054529/486233)

```
RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]
```