# Case insensitive in wordpress urls

Tags: wordpress, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have a wordpress with Hostgator,
When I type site.com/Author goes to 404 Error page not to site.com/author.
I need that code to add it in .htacess file to do that redirect. Any help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force lower case of URLs - Override previous rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048192/force-lower-case-of-urls-override-previous-rules)

Comment: @rnevius it does not work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer: Just add this code in your .htaccess

```
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
```

Or use this plugin : [Link](http://www.unfocus.com/.../case-insensitive-permalinks-plugin-for-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

mod_speling does not work with mod_rewrite which is used by wordpress. The two modules are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try out with this content in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# If there are caps, set HASCAPS to true and skip next rule
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [E=HASCAPS:TRUE,S=1]
# Skip this entire section if no uppercase letters in requested URL
RewriteRule ![A-Z] - [S=28]
# Replace single occurance of CAP with cap, then process next Rule.
RewriteRule ^([^A]*)A(.*)$ $1a$2
RewriteRule ^([^B]*)B(.*)$ $1b$2
RewriteRule ^([^C]*)C(.*)$ $1c$2
RewriteRule ^([^D]*)D(.*)$ $1d$2
RewriteRule ^([^E]*)E(.*)$ $1e$2
RewriteRule ^([^F]*)F(.*)$ $1f$2
RewriteRule ^([^G]*)G(.*)$ $1g$2
RewriteRule ^([^H]*)H(.*)$ $1h$2
RewriteRule ^([^I]*)I(.*)$ $1i$2
RewriteRule ^([^J]*)J(.*)$ $1j$2
RewriteRule ^([^K]*)K(.*)$ $1k$2
RewriteRule ^([^L]*)L(.*)$ $1l$2
RewriteRule ^([^M]*)M(.*)$ $1m$2
RewriteRule ^([^N]*)N(.*)$ $1n$2
RewriteRule ^([^O]*)O(.*)$ $1o$2
RewriteRule ^([^P]*)P(.*)$ $1p$2
RewriteRule ^([^Q]*)Q(.*)$ $1q$2
RewriteRule ^([^R]*)R(.*)$ $1r$2
RewriteRule ^([^S]*)S(.*)$ $1s$2
RewriteRule ^([^T]*)T(.*)$ $1t$2
RewriteRule ^([^U]*)U(.*)$ $1u$2
RewriteRule ^([^V]*)V(.*)$ $1v$2
RewriteRule ^([^W]*)W(.*)$ $1w$2
RewriteRule ^([^X]*)X(.*)$ $1x$2
RewriteRule ^([^Y]*)Y(.*)$ $1y$2
RewriteRule ^([^Z]*)Z(.*)$ $1z$2

# If there are any uppercase letters, restart at very first RewriteRule in file.
RewriteRule [A-Z] - [N]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HASCAPS} TRUE
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I add this at the end of .htaccess and no results.

Comment: This a bad code, I add it then many problems happened to my site.

Comment: This looks like incredibly dangerous code, you should not need to rewrite individual letters like this.