# Can i modify a link from a custom template?

Tags: html, wordpress

So this is the problem, the url button is not pointing to the right place i would like to know if is possible to modify the html files using only wordpress or if wordpress have some kind of plugin editor to do this work.

I have no acces to the server files, i only can modify through wordpress.

Here is the site:

http://a4mexico.com.mx/

The "INICIO" button is pointing to

`a4mexico.com.mx/Inicio` instead of

`a4mexico.com.mx/inicio`

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive in wordpress urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26510289/case-insensitive-in-wordpress-urls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is easy if you used any plugin for custom js like  https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/

just put these code there and save

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   if ($('.button-link').attr('href')== 'lnicio') ? $('.button-link').attr('href', 'inicio'): '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit WordPress theme file from the admin panel. You can use default editor or the plugin [Code editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-code-editor/)

You should take a back up of both files and database before making any changes in the website. You can use [Duplicator](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

[2](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes): https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ plugin for taking the backup.

If theme developers are providing regular updates in theme it is not good to edit the theme directly. In this case you should create a child theme and make the edit. For creating child theme refer the [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)